# avoid double events (onclick) with nested ul / li

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a two-level ul/li menu where the li can fire of different onclick-events.

It seems as the parent-event (ul li), is fired when clicking one ul li ul li-item.

Can I avoid this an easy way.

(I'm considering using timer to trap second event, but think of it as an ugly fix...)

Regards,
/T

Comment: are you using straight javascript or a js library to set events?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you have to stop the event bubbling 
so if you are using straight javascript you have `event.cancelBubble = true`

otherwise if you're using jQuery you have `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: cancelBubble is non standard (internet explorer) although it seems some other browsers support it. To be correct you should also use `event.stopPropagation()` if it is available

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `event.stopPropagation()` consider:

```
function myFunction() {
    if (event.myFunctionResolved == undefined) {
        event.myFunctionResolved = true;

        // your logic here
    }
}
```

The advantage here is that the event won't be stopped and hence other scripts that might be listening for that event will be executed.